# 'Oracle:Oracle-Linux:7.0:latest'

Tags: linux, azure

Hi I am trying to deploy a Oracle Linux 7.0.0.0.0 VM but get this error message.
Is this only available to MSDN users? I have not seen anything to illustrate this when creating it or on other websites.

STATUSMESSAGE{
  "error": {
    "code": "ImageNotFound",
    "target": "imageReference",
    "message": "The platform image 'Oracle:Oracle-Linux:7.0:latest' is not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct."
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I can see below images available in Oracle

```
data:    Name                                                                                                                  Category  OS       Publisher
data:    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------  -------  
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-6-12-2014                                                              Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-6-E-Database-2014                                                      Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-64                                                                     Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-67                                                                     Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-68                                                                     Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-7                                                                      Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-70                                                                     Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-72                                                                     Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-Database-Standard-2014                                                 Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__WebLogic-Linux-6-12c-2014                                                           Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__db12ee-oracle                                                                       Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__db12se-oracle                                                                       Public    Linux    Oracle
data:    winoracle11g-20150301-11645                                                                                           User      Windows  undefined
```

Please select whichever image is needed for you. If you need oracle Linux without database, you can use latest 7.2 version image `c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-72`